# How can I set different From Email to office365 postfix smtp relay?

Tags: email, office365, smtp, postfix, relay

I have configured the office365 postfix SMTP relay but If I didn't have the same email address I used to authenticate, my mail fails.

How can I send from a different email address?

Say like my configured email with SMTP is abc@test.com but I need to change my from name to bbb@test.com.

Working

```
echo "message"| mail -r"test<abc@test.com>" -s "subject" to@test.com
```

NotWorking

```
echo "message"| mail -r"test<bbb@test.com>" -s "subject" to@test.com
```

I refereed this link to setup office365 postfix smtp relay. 
https://linuxhowtoguide.blogspot.com/2017/03/how-to-configure-postfix-smtp-relay.html

[image: [enter image description here]

Comment: Have you configured a connector in O365 to allow emails from your linux server?, please see this link (on step 6 use your server IP, if the IP is dynamic you will need to update this periodically.) - https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/522-office-365-smtp-relay-connector/

Comment: Will this help to send different from email, Right now I can send email with the same from email I used to authenticate.